# Posterior from a Poisson likelihood and prior

Tags: self-study, prior, bayes, posterior

I have the following Poisson mass function:

$$p(y| \theta) = \frac{\theta^y e^{\theta}}{y!} $$

Which has a corresponding likelihood for *n* independent realizations of y as follows:

$$\frac{e^{-n\theta}\theta^{\sum^n_{i=1}y_i}}{\prod_{i=1}^ny_i!}$$

Now I have that the prior is $1/\theta$, so I think that the posterior would be:
$$p(\theta| y)=\frac{e^{-n\theta}\theta^{(\sum^n_{i=1}{y_i})-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^ny_i!}$$
a. Can you please tell me if this is correct?

I am also supposed to simulate 1000 observations from that posterior in R, but what I don't understand is how to do that. I mean, the posterior is giving me a probability, not an observation, so how I am supposed to create observations from that posterior? I can't use *rpois()* because because the posterior is not exactly a poisson, is it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 2):

thats not quite correct. Bayes rule gives you $$p(θ|y)=p(y|θ)p(θ)/p(y)$$ so your result is proportional to the posterior (it doesn't have the right normalizing constant). It looks like the posterior will be  $$Gamma(\alpha=\sum y_i,\beta=n)$$ See [conjugate prior for Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Bayesian_inference)

Comment: Thank you. So what you're saying is: $p(\theta| y)\propto\frac{e^{-n\theta}\theta^{(\sum^n_{i=1}{y_i})-1}}{\prod_{i=1}^ny_i!}$. Just curious, since the denominator does not depend of $\theta$, can I drop it and still say that is proportional to the posterior?

Comment: @user280809 you're asking whether something that is proportional to another thing is still proportional to it if you multiply by a constant?

Comment: Yes also note originally I had wrong sign on beta

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, as you can see my knowledge of statistics is not very good and I am wondering if the denominator is actually a constant since one can change the _n_ but from the tone of your response I assume that it is constant.

Comment: @bdeonovic Thank you for your patience and help, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Note your prior is a specific gamma. So you have discovered Poisson gamma conjugacy